# What are the equivalent Ubuntu 20.04 packages for these Ubuntu 18.04 packages?

Tags: 18.04, apt, software-installation, 20.04

I'm trying to install a bunch of packages, but the install script was made for Ubuntu 18.04. I have a few that I'm having trouble with in 20.04. Can someone tell me what are the equivalent versions in Ubuntu 20.04? Thanks.

Error message:

```
Package libfluidsynth1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package gudev-1.0
E: Unable to locate package libusb-1.0.0-dev
E: Package 'libfluidsynth1' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libnettle6
E: Unable to locate package libopenexr22
```

Edit: I'm also having trouble with `libgfortran3`.

Comment: Tip: The `devscripts` package contains a very handy tool called `rmadison` that will answer most of these for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are trying the same.

```
libgfortran3 -> libgfortran5
gudev-1.0 -> gir1.2-gudev-1.0
libusb-1.0.0-dev -> libusb-1.0-0-dev
libfluidsynth1 -> libfluidsynth2
libnettle6 -> libnettle7
libopenexr22 -> libopenexr24
```

Answer (score 1):

libfluidsynth1 Real-time MIDI software synthesizer has been upgraded to libfluidsynth2 in Ubuntu 20.04 and later. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install libfluidsynth2
```

To install libgfortran3 in 18.04 type:

```
sudo apt install libgfortran3
```